# How do I AutoScroll with react-sortable-hoc (Table)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-virtualized, react-sortable-hoc

I've been struggling to implement [this example](https://clauderic.github.io/react-sortable-hoc/#/react-virtualized/sortable-table-rows?_k=sc9y3r) noted in the `react-sortable-hoc` examples page, specifically with the autoscroll behavior within a table. Unfortunately it doesn't look as though source code lives in the examples directory of the repository.

Although the code I've implemented in the codesandbox below is a very simple example, I've been pouring over this for hours, using `useWindowAsScrollContainer` and `getContainer` with refs, but nothing seems to resolve the issue.

That said, here's the behavior I'm noting: when scrolling out of the container, and even out of the window, the autoscroll feature never engages. I even resorted to returning `document.body` with `getContainer` which should limit the container, but can't seem to replicate the behavior as noted in [the repository's example](https://clauderic.github.io/react-sortable-hoc/#/react-virtualized/sortable-table-rows?_k=sc9y3r).

Also, although I've specified a fixed height and width on the `SortableTable` component, ideally this should be wrapped with `<AutoSizer />`, but removed that for the time being to eliminate any side effects.

https://codesandbox.io/s/mysortabletable-zi94g?file=/MySortableTable.js

- **react-sortable-hoc**: 1.11.0
- **react-virtualized**: 9.7.5

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to provider the container to the Sortable component to which it must restrict the `sortableElement` when using 3rd party libraries for rendering using the `getContainer` prop.

As per the react-sortable-hoc documentation:

> `getContainer` is an Optional function to return the scrollable container element. This
>   property defaults to the `SortableContainer` element itself or (if
>   `useWindowAsScrollContainer` is true) the window. Use this function to
>   specify a custom container object (eg this is useful for integrating
>   with certain 3rd party components such as FlexTable). This function is
>   passed a single parameter (the wrappedInstance React element) and it
>   is expected to return a DOM element.

Now since you cannot pass a direct ref to the child, you can write a small wrapper over the Table component before passing it to the HOC

```
const MyTable = ({ tableRef, ...rest }) => {
    return <Table ref={this.props.tableRef} {...rest} />;
}
const SortableTable = SortableContainer(MyTable);
const SortableTableRowRenderer = SortableElement(defaultTableRowRenderer);

/**
 * Define the table schema
 */
const schema = [
  { dataKey: "col1", label: "Column 1" },
  { dataKey: "col2", label: "Column 2" }
];

/**
 * Generate row data according to the schema above
 * @param {*} rowCount
 */
function generateRows(rowCount) {
  const rows = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
    rows.push({ col1: i, col2: i * i });
  }
  return rows;
}

class MySortableTable extends Component {
  state = {
    schema,
    rows: generateRows(200)
  };

  onSortEnd = ({ oldIndex, newIndex }) => {
    this.setState(({ rows }) => ({
      rows: arrayMove(rows, oldIndex, newIndex)
    }));
  };

  rowRenderer = props => {
    return <SortableTableRowRenderer {...props} />;
  };

  getRow = ({ index }) => {
    const { rows } = this.state;
    return rows[index];
  };

  render() {
    const { rows, schema } = this.state;

    return (
      <SortableTable
        width={500}
        height={500}
        headerHeight={32}
        rowHeight={32}
        tableRef={ref => (this.tableRef = ref)}
        getContainer={() => ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.tableRef.Grid)}
        rowCount={rows.length}
        rowGetter={this.getRow}
        onSortEnd={this.onSortEnd}
        rowRenderer={this.rowRenderer}
      >
        {schema.map(col => (
          <Column {...col} key={col.dataKey} width={100} />
        ))}
      </SortableTable>
    );
  }
}
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/mysortabletable-4xvbx?file=/MySortableTable.js:303-2092)

Comment: This is brilliant - thank you very much, I knew I was missing something with a ref to the table, and this is it. I'm going to attempt to wrap this with <AutoSizer /> and hopefully I don't hit any subsequent issues. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to have helped :-)

Comment: Thanks! Even though it's a bit outdate as we are now mostly using functional components. The important bit here is `getContainer={() => ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.tableRef.Grid)}`